Does join of simplicial sets preserve $(\infty,1)$-categorical localizations?
Let us take Definition 6.3.1.9(01MP) from Lurie's Kerodon for the definition of localization between simplicial sets (with notation deviated). That is:
Definition. Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a map of simplicial sets, and $W\subseteq X_1$ be a set of edges. We say that $f$ exhibits $Y$ as the localization of $X$ at $W$ if, for any quasi-category $Q$, the precomposition map $f^*\colon \operatorname{Fun}(Y, Q)\to\operatorname{Fun}(X,Q)$ factors through the simplicial subset $\operatorname{Fun}((X,W),Q^\natural)\subseteq\operatorname{Fun}(X,Q)$, and induces an equivalence $\operatorname{Fun}(Y, Q)\overset{\sim}{\to}\operatorname{Fun}((X,W),Q^\natural)$ of quasi-categories. Here, $\operatorname{Fun}(X,Q)$ denotes the internal hom in the cartesian closed 1-category $\mathbf{SSet}$ of simplicial sets, and $\operatorname{Fun}((X,W),Q^\natural)$ is the simplicial subset of simplicial maps that map edges in $W$ to equivalences in $Q$.
Question. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a map between simplicial sets, and assume that $f$ exhibits $Y$ as the localization of $X$ at $W\subseteq X_1$. If $K$ is another simplicial set. Does the map $f\star\mathrm{id}_K\colon X\star K\to Y\star K$ always exhibit $Y\star K$ as the localization of $X\star K$ at $W\subseteq X_1= (X\star\emptyset)_1\subseteq (X\star K)_1$?
I suspect it should be completely elementary to prove, but I don't know exactly how. The facts I see are the following:

Following definitions, it is easy to see that $(f\star\mathrm{id}_K)^*\colon \operatorname{Fun}(Y\star K, Q)\to\operatorname{Fun}(X\star K,Q)$ factors through $\operatorname{Fun}((X\star K,W),Q^\natural)$.
The factored map $\operatorname{Fun}(Y\star K, Q)\to\operatorname{Fun}((X\star K,W),Q^\natural)$ is a fiberwise equivalence of categories over $\operatorname{Fun}(K,Q)$, because for each point $h\colon K \to Q$ of $\operatorname{Fun}(K,Q)$, the map between the fibers over $h$ may be written as $\operatorname{Fun}(Y, Q_{/h})\to\operatorname{Fun}((X,W),(Q_{/h})^\natural)$.
The maps $\operatorname{Fun}(Y\star K, Q)\to\operatorname{Fun}(K,Q)$ and $\operatorname{Fun}((X\star K,W), Q^\natural)\to\operatorname{Fun}(K,Q)$ are Joyal fibrations (i.e., isofibrations of quasi-categories). See Corollary 4.4.5.3 (01F3) and Remark 6.3.1.8 (01MN).

However I have no idea how to proceed. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

The join $X\star Y$ can be described, up to categorical equivalence, as $X\coprod_{X\times Y\times\{0\}}(X\times Y\times\Delta^1)\coprod_{X\times Y\times\{1\}} Y$, cf. Theorem 4.5.8.8 (01HV) in Kerodon.
From this perspective, the result becomes clear since products preserve localizations (cf. Proposition 6.3.5.6 (02LV) in Kerodon). Since mapping into a quasi-category only depends on a simplicial set up to categorical equivalence, and the map from the joint to the "blunt joint" is natural, you get the desired result.

Thanks for a nice, concise proof! Excuse me I submitted an edit that adds some links to Kerodon.
